# Is it considered good practice to use AND as a logic gate?

Tags: ruby, conditional-statements

I'm both new to ruby and to programming in general. While working my way thru "The Well-Grounded Rubyist" book I came across this expression from the set.rb standard library:

`enum.nil? and return`

It seems like an odd (but clever) way to do this:

`return unless enum.nil?`

It that a common technique? Also, why do it that way? Am I missing something?

Here's the full code snippet:

```
def initialize(enum = nil, &block)
  @hash ||= Hash.new

  enum.nil? and return

  if block
    do_with_enum(enum) { |o| add(block[o]) }
  else
    merge(enum)
  end
end
```

Comment: I've not seen that before, but it works, of course.  I much prefer `return unless..` for readability.  You may have some objections to the question because it calls for opinions, which is out-of-bounds on SO.  Incidentally, in this context `&&` is generally used instead of `and`.

Comment: Second the readability issue. `and` is uncommon enough that it doesn't really register as a conditional statement at first glance the way `return if enum.nil?` or `return unless enum` would. @CarySwoveland - I believe `and` (a control flow operator) is actually **more** appropriate in this context than `&&` (a boolean operator) would be.

Comment: @Zach, I agree with you re `and` vs `&&`, though many Rubiests never use `and`; just `&&` with parentheses as needed.  My statement above does suggest it is "better" to use `&&`, which is not correct.

Comment: `if condition and false` or `if condition or true` - if I want to test or to block if-branch

Comment: Huh. I thought `enum.nil? and return` is equivalent to `return if enum.nil?` and `!enum.nil? and return` is equivalent to `return unless enum.nil?`. The idiom `enum.nil? and return` is not "idiomatic" in Ruby; You'll find it in Perl a lot, and there's a lot of Ruby developers who came from Perl, but in general Rubyists go with the trailing `if` form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [Avdi Grimm's article](http://devblog.avdi.org/2010/08/02/using-and-and-or-in-ruby/) on this subject, the keywords `and` and `or` are used for flow control operators in ruby, as opposed to being boolean operators.

You are correct that `enum.nil? and return` is the same as `return unless enum.nil?`. I would agree with you that in this case using `unless` would be more readable.

This pattern isn't *uncommon* in ruby, the reason it's done this way is to show intention of flow control by making use of the low precedence of the `and` operator. Since this operator has low precedence, it allows you to add more actions chained on with subsequent `and`'s without conflicting with other operations that may be done in that same line of code. However, most would consider explicitly gating a condition with an `if` the preferable way to control flow.

Comment: I get it now. I thought `and` and `&&` were synonymous.